# How to dynamicaly set multi column header of the Primefaces PanelGrid

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to dynamicaly create primefaces PanelGrid with column names for each column.

My code looks like this:

```
private void setPanelGridHeader(PanelGrid grid, String[] columnNames) {
    Row row = null;
    Column col = null;
    String columnName = null;
    OutputLabel label = null;

    grid.setColumns(columnNames.length);

    row = new Row();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        columnName = columnNames[i];
        label = new OutputLabel();
        label.setValue(columnName);

        col = new Column();
        row.getChildren().add(col);
        col.getChildren().add(label);
    }

    grid.getFacets().put("header", row);
}
```

It works fine if I add single component HtmlOutputText, but when I try to add row and columns only tiny empty row is created.

Expected output is:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column> A </p:column>
        <p:column> B </p:column>
        <p:column> . </p:column>
        <p:column> . </p:column>
    </p:row>

</f:facet>
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any alternatives?

I have just found out that using primefaces 5.1 even facelets doesn't work as expected:

```
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column > A </p:column>
                    <p:column > BBBBB </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="aaaaa" />
            <h:outputText value="b" />
        </p:panelGrid>
```

produces (expected is comented):

```
<thead class="ui-panelgrid-header">
    <tr class="ui-widget-header" role="row">
        <td colspan="2" role="columnheader">A BBBBB</td>

        <!-- EXPECTED TWOCOLUMN HEADER ------------------<<<<<<<<
        <td role="columnheader">A</td>
        <td role="columnheader">BBBBB</td>
         -->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">aaaaa</td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">b</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This may be a bug. Any workarounds?